# Error when trying to load from Firebase through recursion

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to load in an array of team names that I want to put up on different table view cells, but it never seems to load them properly.

I've been trying to cause the program to wait until it gets values back, but it never seems to get any, since it always crashes, gets a loading error, or just freezes.

```
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var teamData = [String]()
    var teamCount : Int?
    var hasfilled = false
    var firstRun = false
    var currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        //Load each team
        let path = ref?.child("Users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("joinedTeams")
        path?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot{
                let teamName = rest.value as? String
                if let teamNameData = teamName {
                    self.teamData.append(teamNameData)
                }
            }
            self.teamCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        })
        if runTillCompletion() == true {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func runTillCompletion() -> Bool{
        if self.teamCount == self.teamData.count {
            return true
        }

        return runTillCompletion()
    }
```

I've tried this several different ways, from a while loop to just reloading it a ton.

I want to reload the view so that it runs the table view methods that determine the number of cells/content of cells.

I'm certain that there a better way to do this, since using a while loop/the recursion function have been painfully messy.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your runTillCompletion method is called earlier before the response from Firebase and hence the tableview is empty. You need to reload the table after fetching data from firebase.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    //Load each team
    let path = ref?.child("Users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("joinedTeams")
    path?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot{
            let teamName = rest.value as? String
            if let teamNameData = teamName {
                self.teamData.append(teamNameData)
            }
        }
        self.teamCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users/\(currentUser!.uid)/joinedTeams")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            self.teamData = snapshots.flatMap { $0.value as? String }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Just tried this. It does crashed an manages to segue to the tableview without freezing, but it doesn't load anything. I put down a breakpoint at the end of the observe, and both self.teamCount and self.teamData are empty.

Comment: What do you mean at the end of the observe? You need to put the breakpoint inside the `observeSingleEvent(of: ..., with:` block. Also please add your `UITableViewDataSource` methods to your question